# esp8266 with arduino uno getting bad request

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266

I am developing an arduino project in which i have to send some data on internet to my server.
but the problem is that i am always getting bad request (HTTP 400). 
i have both php & asp.net servers available but neither of them are accepting the connection
 I am Using The Command Below On ESP8266 To Send The Data

```
GET /update?data=test HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: mydomain.com\r\n\r\n
```

I found out that i have to send some more headers but i dont know how to send those headers.
Please Help.

Thank You

Comment: That request should work. Where did you find out, that you need some additional headers? Are you sending to an existing API?

Comment: Did you try your api (update) with any api debugger (like DHC or Rest Easy) to make sure that you can mimick the problems you have with your ESP8266 code ?

Comment: Can you post your whole code? Where are you seeing the "Bad Request" error? The server log, or you are reading it from the response sent by the server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure that there is mandatory headers but I usually add a few more. My usual requests are like that :

```
GET /update?data=test HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: mydomain.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n
```

Hope this helps.